# libssh: Memory lost in simple implementation

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, valgrind, libssh

I am trying a very simple implementation of `libssh` but valgrind shows memory leak.

**The code is:**

```
#include <libssh/libssh.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
        ssh_session my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
        int port = 22;
        int rc, state;
        const char *ip = "192.168.125.241";
        char *password;
        if (my_ssh_session == NULL)
                exit(-1);
        ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, ip);
        ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);
        rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
        if (rc != SSH_OK)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting to localhost: %s\n",
                ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
                exit(-1);
        }

        state = ssh_is_server_known(my_ssh_session);
        if(state == SSH_SERVER_KNOWN_OK)
                printf("already added\n");
        else
                printf("require addition\n");

        rc = ssh_userauth_password(my_ssh_session, "rohit", "password");
        if (rc != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error authenticating with password: %s\n",
                ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
                ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
                ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
                exit(-1);
        }
        ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
        ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
}
```

**COMPILATION:**

```
gcc sshex.c -lssh
```

**VALGRIND RUN:**

```
root@rohit-Precision-T1500:/# valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --show-reachable=no ./a.out 
==1937== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1937== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1937== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1937== Command: ./a.out
==1937== 
yahoo
==1937== 
==1937== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1937==     in use at exit: 14,256 bytes in 521 blocks
==1937==   total heap usage: 1,339 allocs, 818 frees, 92,442 bytes allocated
==1937== 
==1937== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 507 of 520
==1937==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1937==    by 0x56AAD32: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x56E3A59: BN_new (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x56E3F07: BN_bin2bn (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x4E6079B: pki_signature_from_blob (pki_crypto.c:1384)
==1937==    by 0x4E599F9: ssh_pki_import_signature_blob (pki.c:1262)
==1937==    by 0x4E59A77: ssh_pki_signature_verify_blob (pki.c:1281)
==1937==    by 0x4E578DE: ssh_packet_newkeys (packet_cb.c:186)
==1937==    by 0x4E56E6F: ssh_packet_process (packet.c:422)
==1937==    by 0x4E57374: ssh_packet_socket_callback (packet.c:326)
==1937==    by 0x4E573B3: ssh_packet_socket_callback (packet.c:336)
==1937==    by 0x4E5D951: ssh_socket_pollcallback (socket.c:290)
==1937== 
==1937== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 508 of 520
==1937==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1937==    by 0x56AAD32: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x56E3A59: BN_new (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x56E3F07: BN_bin2bn (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x4E607EC: pki_signature_from_blob (pki_crypto.c:1405)
==1937==    by 0x4E599F9: ssh_pki_import_signature_blob (pki.c:1262)
==1937==    by 0x4E59A77: ssh_pki_signature_verify_blob (pki.c:1281)
==1937==    by 0x4E578DE: ssh_packet_newkeys (packet_cb.c:186)
==1937==    by 0x4E56E6F: ssh_packet_process (packet.c:422)
==1937==    by 0x4E57374: ssh_packet_socket_callback (packet.c:326)
==1937==    by 0x4E573B3: ssh_packet_socket_callback (packet.c:336)
==1937==    by 0x4E5D951: ssh_socket_pollcallback (socket.c:290)
==1937== 
==1937== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 511 of 520
==1937==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1937==    by 0x56AAD32: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x56E35E6: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x56E3AD4: bn_expand2 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x56E3ECF: BN_bin2bn (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x4E6079B: pki_signature_from_blob (pki_crypto.c:1384)
==1937==    by 0x4E599F9: ssh_pki_import_signature_blob (pki.c:1262)
==1937==    by 0x4E59A77: ssh_pki_signature_verify_blob (pki.c:1281)
==1937==    by 0x4E578DE: ssh_packet_newkeys (packet_cb.c:186)
==1937==    by 0x4E56E6F: ssh_packet_process (packet.c:422)
==1937==    by 0x4E57374: ssh_packet_socket_callback (packet.c:326)
==1937==    by 0x4E573B3: ssh_packet_socket_callback (packet.c:336)
==1937== 
==1937== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 512 of 520
==1937==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1937==    by 0x56AAD32: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x56E35E6: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x56E3AD4: bn_expand2 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x56E3ECF: BN_bin2bn (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x4E607EC: pki_signature_from_blob (pki_crypto.c:1405)
==1937==    by 0x4E599F9: ssh_pki_import_signature_blob (pki.c:1262)
==1937==    by 0x4E59A77: ssh_pki_signature_verify_blob (pki.c:1281)
==1937==    by 0x4E578DE: ssh_packet_newkeys (packet_cb.c:186)
==1937==    by 0x4E56E6F: ssh_packet_process (packet.c:422)
==1937==    by 0x4E57374: ssh_packet_socket_callback (packet.c:326)
==1937==    by 0x4E573B3: ssh_packet_socket_callback (packet.c:336)
==1937== 
==1937== 48 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 513 of 520
==1937==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1937==    by 0x56AAD32: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x56E3A59: BN_new (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x574C358: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x5750B1A: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x5750BC5: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x5750D79: ASN1_item_new (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x4E60734: pki_signature_from_blob (pki_crypto.c:1347)
==1937==    by 0x4E599F9: ssh_pki_import_signature_blob (pki.c:1262)
==1937==    by 0x4E59A77: ssh_pki_signature_verify_blob (pki.c:1281)
==1937==    by 0x4E578DE: ssh_packet_newkeys (packet_cb.c:186)
==1937==    by 0x4E56E6F: ssh_packet_process (packet.c:422)
==1937== 
==1937== 128 (16 direct, 112 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 516 of 520
==1937==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1937==    by 0x56AAD32: CRYPTO_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x5750D0B: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x5750D79: ASN1_item_new (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==1937==    by 0x4E60734: pki_signature_from_blob (pki_crypto.c:1347)
==1937==    by 0x4E599F9: ssh_pki_import_signature_blob (pki.c:1262)
==1937==    by 0x4E59A77: ssh_pki_signature_verify_blob (pki.c:1281)
==1937==    by 0x4E578DE: ssh_packet_newkeys (packet_cb.c:186)
==1937==    by 0x4E56E6F: ssh_packet_process (packet.c:422)
==1937==    by 0x4E57374: ssh_packet_socket_callback (packet.c:326)
==1937==    by 0x4E573B3: ssh_packet_socket_callback (packet.c:336)
==1937==    by 0x4E5D951: ssh_socket_pollcallback (socket.c:290)
==1937== 
==1937== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1937==    definitely lost: 64 bytes in 3 blocks
==1937==    indirectly lost: 112 bytes in 4 blocks
==1937==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1937==    still reachable: 14,080 bytes in 514 blocks
==1937==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1937== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
```

**DIRECT RUN:**

```
root@rohit-Precision-T1500:/# gcc sshex.c -lssh
root@rohit-Precision-T1500:/# ./a.out 
already added
root@rohit-Precision-T1500:/#
```

**LINUX VERSION:**

```
root@rohit-Precision-T1500:/# uname -a
Linux rohit-Precision-T1500 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have experimented on this. If I remove the function `ssh_connect()` (and other following functions of course), then I don't get any leak. So, the leak must have been raised by this function. But in my little program, I have used the function `ssh_disconnect()` to release the memory allocated by `ssh_connect()`. So, How can I make sure the memory is freed for sure?

I would like to use SCP functionality in my software and that will be a long lived process. So, the memory leak is going to be a serious concern.
As per my understanding, the leaks are associated with `libcrypto` library which probably is not leak of `libssh`. If, it is or otherwise, what is the solution to get rid of these leaks?
Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't you require a `ssh_free(my_ssh_session);` after `fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting to localhost: %s\n", ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));` ?

Comment: That wouldn't change a thing. The program is anyhow going to terminate and free all memory after the block you are indicating. I have pasted valgrind log of a successful program run.

Comment: Can you post the program's output?

Comment: Updated. Please find content under **DIRECT RUN** in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened as I suspected. This could be the bug in `libcrypto`. I ran my program in `RHEL 6.5` and valgrind showed no leaks.

Here is the snippet of the output:

```
[root@demo-hadoop test]# gcc sshex.c -lssh
[root@demo-hadoop test]# valgrind --tool=memcheck ./a.out 
==23636== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==23636== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==23636== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==23636== Command: ./a.out
==23636== 
already added
==23636== 
==23636== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23636==     in use at exit: 15,304 bytes in 532 blocks
==23636==   total heap usage: 1,067 allocs, 535 frees, 82,199 bytes allocated
==23636== 
==23636== LEAK SUMMARY:
==23636==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23636==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23636==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23636==    still reachable: 15,304 bytes in 532 blocks
==23636==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23636== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==23636== 
==23636== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==23636== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
[root@demo-hadoop test]# 
[root@demo-hadoop test]# 
[root@demo-hadoop test]# uname -a
Linux demo-hadoop 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Nov 10 22:19:54 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So, of course, this is not a bug in `libssh`.